# Simplexml won't add children or attributes to xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My xml (hashes.xml) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <updated></updated>
    <players>
        <playernum>1</playernum>
        <!--Demonstration of syntax, using the value 127.0.0.1 and the first second of December 22, 2012 with salt of 000 -->
        <player id="7bea7450391c9d89c65af7a46966e45066105fa4">
            <game id="1">
                <color>red</color>
            </game>
            <game id="2">
                <color>purple</color>
            </game>
        </player>
    </players>
</root>
```

And my php is

```
<?php

$hash = $_GET["hash"];

$xml = simplexml_load_file("hashes.xml");
$xml->players->addChild("player", " ");

?>
```

But when I run the php it makes no changes to the xml file. I am open to using any method even if it's not simplexml.

Comment: Did you actually save the XML back out with soemthing like `file_put_contents('hashes.xml', $xml->asXml());`?

Comment: I did not. That might be my problem. EDIT: Nope. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You already have `player` child in your `players`.
I think you need another name for `players` parent `$xml->players->addChild("player2", " ");`

Edit: as I tested the code I saw I was wrong

this actually works

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <updated></updated>
    <players>
        <playernum>1</playernum>
        <!--Demonstration of syntax, using the value 127.0.0.1 and the first second of December 22, 2012 with salt of 000 -->
        <player id="7bea7450391c9d89c65af7a46966e45066105fa4">
            <game id="1">
                <color>red</color>
            </game>
            <game id="2">
                <color>purple</color>
            </game>
        </player>
    </players>
</root>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$newPlayer = $xml->players->addChild("player", " ");
$newPlayer->addAttribute("id", "12313123123");
$newGame = $newPlayer->addChild("game", "");
$newGame->addAttribute("id", "1");
$newColor = $newGame->addChild("color", "blue");
echo $xml->asXML();
```

the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root> 
    <updated/> 
    <players> 
        <playernum>1</playernum> 
        <!--Demonstration of syntax, using the value 127.0.0.1 and the first second of December 22, 2012 with salt of 000 --> 
        <player id="7bea7450391c9d89c65af7a46966e45066105fa4"> 
            <game id="1"> 
                <color>red</color> 
            </game> 
            <game id="2"> 
                <color>purple</color> 
            </game> 
        </player> 
        <player id="12313123123">
            <game id="1">
                <color>blue</color>
            </game>
        </player>
    </players> 
</root>
```

Comment: But even when I change "echo $xml->asXML();" to "$xml->asXML("hashes.xml");" the changes don't show up in hashes.xml

Comment: The log file says that permission was denied so it couldn't open the stream.